# Is it a good idea to use strings for all data types in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

So as an example, which is better practice when designing JSON that is returned from the server :

Approach1 : Returning values as the correct types :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

Or

Approach2 : Wrapping all values in double-quotes as follows :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": "12.50",
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

Which approach is better? What are the pros and cons of each approach? Are there any tradeoffs?

Comment: Well, doesn't it defeat the point of having distinct types? If you're in a situation where everything *must* be a string, then obviously you're going to use a string. If you're not, then why would you?

Comment: Depends on whether you want numbers, booleans, etc. or strings. No there's no advantage I can think of to strings except for numeric precision beyond what a given programming language in the stack can handle.

Comment: Ultimately this is either a matter of opinion, or requires knowledge of the context of its use.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The client that consumes the API wants different data types such as int, long, double, float, boolean and string.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to only use quotes for actual strings, and not for any other types like integers.

By storing everything as a string any app that parses the json and expects an int but gets a string instead will throw an exception. It can also have an impact on performance as strings use up more memory than other types.

Depending on the situation you could off course write or find a parser that takes care of the type conversion, but it's easier to just use quotes as intended.

So unless you have to feed this json into an existing app that expects every type to be stored as a string I don't see any reason to use quotes for all types.

Answer (score 0):

A loss of precision is not advantageous. You're throwing away inherent meaning. If it is easier for you based on your application to do this, then it is just fine; just be aware of what you are doing.

Comment: What do you mean by "a loss of precision"?